# twiddle with jboss 6.1.0 As version

Tags: jboss

Trying to invoke with twiddle command with jboss 6.1.0 AS for checking/starting/stoping the  of war deployment, but it get failed with below error message:

Command : 
    ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/twiddle.sh -s service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:/jmxrmi invoke 'jboss.web.deployment:war=/'${WAR_NAME} start
Error Message:

```
org.jboss.util.NestedRuntimeException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; - nested throwable: (java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused])
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle$1.getServer(Twiddle.java:221)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.MBeanServerCommand.getMBeanServer(MBeanServerCommand.java:64)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.GetCommand.execute(GetCommand.java:149)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.main(Twiddle.java:370)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.createMBeanServerConnection(Twiddle.java:322)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.connect(Twiddle.java:331)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.access$400(Twiddle.java:60)
        at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle$1.getServer(Twiddle.java:217)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1929)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1896)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:286)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:114)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 18 more
```

Any help would be appreciable :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of my query :)

In jboss 5.1.0 Naming port used however jboss -6.1.0 AS using RMI port.

so command would be :
${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/twiddle.sh -s service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:${RMI PORT}/jmxrmi invoke 'jboss.web.deployment:war=/'${WAR_NAME} start

Thanks